# Doing AngularJS validation without making use of form element?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to make use of the angularJS validation tools without wrapping the controls in a form, and what would this be called?

Normal angularjs form validation example:

```
<form name="form" class="form-validation">    
    <p class="text-muted">Please fill the information to continue</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username <em class="text-muted">(allow 'a-zA-Z0-9', 4-10 length)</em></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,10}$/" required >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label>Email</label>
         <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" required >
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: angular js validation works only with form. This is there in architecture of angularjs. Angular creates property from form name in current scope and stores all the validation in that property object. So it's require to create form for angular validation

Comment: Why don't you want a form tag ?

Comment: My submit button is not on the same layer as my editable fields. It feels like a cheap move wrapping everything in a form element.